# How to draw curved arrows linking two nodes and how to put an icon in the corner of a node?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, tikz-node, fontawesome

I'm trying to make a diagram but I'm having some issues:

1. I'd like to have a curver arrow linking node 5 to node 1.
2. I'd like the icons on image nodes to be on the upper right corner.
3. I wanted to put more information under the arrow linking nodes 1 and 2.

This is what I have so far:

[image: Current diagram.]

To generate this diagram, I used the following source code:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fontawesome}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning, arrows}

\tikzstyle{smallerblock} = [rectangle, draw, 
text width=2.0cm, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em]
\tikzstyle{largerblock} = [rectangle, draw, 
text width=3.8cm, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em]
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex']

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 0.75cm and 2.5cm, auto]
    % Place nodes
    \node [largerblock] (1) {\small 1};
    \node [largerblock, right=of 1] (2) {2};
    \node [smallerblock, right=of 2] (image) {\small Image \\ (binary) \faFileO};
    \node [largerblock, below=of 2] (4) {4};
    \node [smallerblock, right=of 4] (png) {\small Image \\(png) \faFilePhotoO};
    \node [largerblock, below=of 4] (5) {5};

    % Draw edges
    \path [line] (1) -- node [near start] {1.} (2);
    \path [line] (2) -- (image);
    \path [line] (1) |- node [pos=0.56] {2.} (4);
    \path [line] (image) -- (4);
    \path [line] (4) -- (png);
    \path [line] (png) -- (5);
    \path [line] (1) |- node [pos=0.56] {3.} (5);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This is what I'd like to have:

[image: objective]

If anybody has any idea how to solve one of these issues, or all of them, I'd be truly grateful :)

Comment: `\node [smallerblock, right=of 2, label={[anchor=north east]north east:\small\faFileO}] (image) {\small Image \\ (binary)};` i.e. putting the icon as an extra node (a label) into the corner. (You might need to play with font settings and inner seps a bit.)

Comment: `\path[line] (5) to[out=150, in=-120] node[align=center]{Repeat for\\all variables} (1);` for the curved line for example. Again font sizes, exact angles and stuff like that needs to be fine-tuned.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel thank you so much, that worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note the use of `\tikzset` in the code below instead of `\tikzstyle`. The `\tikzstyle` command works for now, but has been deprecated and may (theoretically) not work in the future. You can set optional arguments and default values in the same `tikzset` as I did below with `noteblock`.

For the curved arrow, you can set `out=` and `in=` angles as options for `to`. Adjusting the `looseness` can change the amount of curve.

For the boxed descriptions you can define an additional style (I used `noteblock`) and treat those labels as additional nodes.

To place the icons, make them additional nodes and position them `below left` of the `north east` corner of the other node.

Note that `\draw` can be used if you wish instead of `\path[draw]` to shorten the code.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fontawesome}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning, arrows}

\tikzset{smallerblock/.style={rectangle, draw, text width=2.0cm, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em},
    largerblock/.style={rectangle, draw, text width=3.8cm, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em},
    line/.style={draw, -latex'},
    noteblock/.style={draw, align=#1, outer sep=2pt, font=\scriptsize},
    noteblock/.default={center}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 0.75cm and 2.5cm, auto]
    % Place nodes
    \node [largerblock] (1) {\small 1};
    \node [largerblock, right=of 1] (2) {2};
    \node [smallerblock, right=of 2] (image) {\small Image \\ (binary)};
    \node [below left=2pt of image.north east]{\small \faFileO};
    \node [largerblock, below=of 2] (4) {4};
    \node [smallerblock, right=of 4] (png) {\small Image \\(png)};
    \node [below left=2pt of png.north east]{\small \faFilePhotoO};
    \node [largerblock, below=of 4] (5) {5};

    % Draw edges
    \path [line] (1) -- node [near start] {1.} node[below, noteblock=left]{- variable\\- integer bits\\- fractional bits} (2);
    \path [line] (2) -- (image);
    \path [line] (1) |- node [pos=0.56] {2.} (4);
    \path [line] (image) -- (4);
    \path [line] (4) -- (png);
    \path [line] (png) -- (5);
    \path [line] (1) |- node [pos=0.56] {3.} (5);
    \path [line, looseness=1.6] (5) to[out=210, in=-120]node[noteblock]{repeat for\\all variables} (1);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I didn't know it had been deprecated, I've updated my code now. Thank you so much, your solution was exactly what I was looking for!